# Как править конфигурацию webpack в приложении, сделанном на create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Необходимо изменить output для того, чтобы билд проекта сразу деплоился на сервере.
Каким образом это можно сделать?
Для меня этот вопрос сейчас важен. 
Я плохо знаю вебпак, но сейчас возникла необходимость делать. 
Нужно ли делать eject для этого или можно воспользоваться каким-то другим путем?
В create-react-app скрыта возможность конфигурировать webpack.
Здесь: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1084
предлагается решение по внесению нескольких путей при помощи eject'a проекта. Не совсем понимаю, подходит ли данное решение.

Comment: Опишите ваш вопрос подробнее, если имеется то подвяжите код который связан с этим вопросом. Ваши наработки кода помогут получить ответ на данный вопрос.

Comment: исправила, возможно, будет более понятно.

Comment: Вам нужно изменить директорию, в которую будет сохраняться билд или вопрос о том, как настроить авто-деплой? Не совсем понятно из вопроса.

Comment: Да, мне нужно исправить директорию. Спасибо, что откликнулись.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо большое всем, кто пытался помочь. 
Необходимо было сделать eject, далее исправить путь в конфиге вебпака.